# Add regression line with geom_smooth to plot with discrete x-axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, linear-regression

I would like to add a regression line from a linear model to a plot in R.

I have created the following sample dataset:

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbeeswarm)

# Set seed
set.seed(123)

# Create dataset
ID <- sprintf("ID-%s",seq(1:30))
baseline <- rnorm(30, mean = 50, sd = 3)

df <- data.frame(ID, baseline) %>%
  mutate(`1` = baseline - rnorm(1, mean = 5, sd = 4), 
         `2` = `1` - rnorm(1, mean = 7, sd = 5), 
         `3` = `2` - rnorm(1, mean = 10, sd = 9)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>% 
  rename(time = name) %>% 
  mutate(time = as.factor(time))
```

Which creates the following plot:

```
# Plot
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=time, y = value)) + 
  geom_quasirandom() +
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("baseline", "1", "2", "3") ) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Value")
```

[image]

If I add  `geom_smooth(method = 'lm')` to the plot, nothing happens and I think it has something to do with the fact that `time` is a factor. However, adding `geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y~as.numeric(x)` also doesn't work.

How do I plot a regression line on top of this graph?

**EDIT1.0:**
I have been able to use geom_smooth to plot a regression line with `geom_smooth(aes(x = as.numeric(time), y = value), method = "lm", formula = y~x)`, but sadly, the regression line is incorrect...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using ordered factor to enable overlay with `aes(as.numeric(time), value)`?

```r
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbeeswarm)

# Set seed
set.seed(123)

# Create dataset
ID <- sprintf("ID-%s",seq(1:30))
baseline <- rnorm(30, mean = 50, sd = 3)

df <- data.frame(ID, baseline) %>%
    mutate(`1` = baseline - rnorm(1, mean = 5, sd = 4), 
           `2` = `1` - rnorm(1, mean = 7, sd = 5), 
           `3` = `2` - rnorm(1, mean = 10, sd = 9)) %>% 
    pivot_longer(-ID) %>% 
    rename(time = name) %>% 
    # create ordered factor to allow synchronized order of x after as.numeric
    mutate(time = factor(time, ordered = T, c("baseline", "1", "2", "3")))  


## rendered results
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=time, y = value)) + 
    geom_quasirandom() +
    theme_classic() + 
    labs(x = "Time", y = "Value") +
    geom_smooth(aes(as.numeric(time), value), method = "lm")
```

[image]

```r
## verify with this
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=time, y = value)) + 
    geom_point() +
    theme_classic() + 
    labs(x = "Time", y = "Value") +
    geom_smooth(aes(as.numeric(time), value), method = "lm")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try this. One option to add a regression line is to compute it manually and add it to the plot via `geom_line` and mapping `ID` on the `group` aesthetic. The red line is the regression line for `value ~ time` while in case of the blue line I recoded time as a numeric, setting "baseline" to 0.

```r
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbeeswarm)

# Set seed
set.seed(123)

# Create dataset
ID <- sprintf("ID-%s",seq(1:30))
baseline <- rnorm(30, mean = 50, sd = 3)

df <- data.frame(ID, baseline) %>%
  mutate(`1` = baseline - rnorm(1, mean = 5, sd = 4), 
         `2` = `1` - rnorm(1, mean = 7, sd = 5), 
         `3` = `2` - rnorm(1, mean = 10, sd = 9)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>% 
  rename(time = name) %>% 
  mutate(time = as.factor(time),
         time1 = ifelse(time == "baseline", 0, as.numeric(time)),
         smooth = predict(lm(value ~ time, data = .)),
         smooth1 = predict(lm(value ~ time1, data = .)))

# Plot
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=time, y = value)) + 
  geom_quasirandom() +
  # Regression line
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = smooth, group = ID), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = smooth1, group = ID), color = "blue") +
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("baseline", "1", "2", "3") ) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Value")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the response! In the example, it seems like 3 different linear models are fitted to the data, while I would like to fit one linear model to all data points. Would this be possible with geom_smooth (especially since it has a convenient `se` option)?

Comment: Yes and no. (; I estimated one linear model. However, as time is a factor it's a model with different intercepts for each level of time (and no slope). That's why we don't get a "nice" line. To achieve this you have to convert the factor to a numeric (as you already tried). In that case question is how to recode "baseline" as a numeric?